# Return top n rows based on threshold from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is my input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],'Industry':['Metals','Metals','IT','IT','IT','banking'],'ROE':[10,9,5,14,1,9],'ROCE':[10,5,5,1,10,9],'Threshold':[1,1,2,2,2,1]});df
```

Need output as follows:

```
dfout = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A','D','E','F'],'Industry':['Metals','IT','IT','banking'],'ROE':[10,14,1,9],'ROCE':[10,1,10,9],'Threshold':[1,2,2,1]});dfout
```

Logic: To fetch rows with top 'n' ROE and ROCE per industry. N is 'Threshold' column in the dataframe. Appreciate your inputs on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort your data by ROE/ROCE:

```
df = df.iloc[(-np.maximum(df.ROCE, df.ROE)).argsort()]
```

Next, use `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby('Industry', group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(
    lambda x: x[:x['Threshold'].unique().item()]
).sort_index()
```

Or,

```
df.groupby('Industry', group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.head(x['Threshold'].unique().item())
).sort_index()
```

```
  Company Industry  ROCE  ROE  Threshold
0       A   Metals    10   10          1
3       D       IT     1   14          2
4       E       IT    10    1          2
5       F  banking     9    9          1
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. I realised that the output should also include Company E because we need to pic companies with top 2 ROCE as well as ROE. So, the final output should include A,C,D,E,F. Please help fine tuning the suggested solution

Comment: @CLS See edit, you can pre-sort `df` and then call this code, I've updated my post with your desired output.

Comment: Great. Thank you